# Integrating php with Salesforce

Tags: authentication, bestpractice, php

I am asked to built a web application in php where the back end database is going to be Salesforce Objects. The scenario is that "users" (can be 10,000+) would register/log in to the application and schedule a slot for an exam. Then take that exam, view their credits and performance.

I would like to know a better approach to start this. Like how would I be able to access the objects using php and how well can I maintain authenticity in this scenario.

Comment: Did you consider a salesforce customer community ?

Comment: If you're looking for a multi-user dumb data store, why not go with [database.com](http://www.database.com/)?

Comment: @Sapthagiri Did you get any solution for this with or without Integrating php ?

Comment: @user40138 I am trying to integrate the systems using WSDL Soap APIs.

Answer (score 3):

You can develop the whole app on salesforce, why using php?

You can take a look at this 
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP

Comment: Well, how would I be able to manage (pricing) bulk users (10,000+). Initially, had thoughts to go completely with Salesforce using force.com sites, however, when the bulk user count came into picture, things started to shake little bit. And so thought that php and Salesforce could be a better option.

Comment: You can create login panel or custom panel with vf and controllers and host them as site . You can make the users as acccount in your org and make fields like username and password, assign photos and other things as attachment.